# If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $X|a < X < b \sim \text{truncated normal}$, is it true that $a < \mu < b$?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

If $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$, then $X$ in the interval $(a, b)$ is a truncated normal. However, does the mean of $X$ have to lie in the interval $(a, b)$ as well? I.e., $a < \mu < b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all. You can take a $N(0,1)$ distribution and truncate it to $[1,2]$.